# How to select items of a SQLite table based on a column with a specific propriety located in another table?

Tags: sql, algorithm, sqlite, select, where-clause

I have the following situation: there are 2 tables in my SQLite database one of which is called "assets" and the other "operations".

"Assets" include a list of market assets each of which having a specific "Asset type" value alongisde its name.

"Operations" have lots of columns one of which being "asset"; each operation is done with one single asset.

Now I have a table in my app I want to populate with "all operations related to a specific asset *type*", something that needs to be done quick. My question is: how can I do this in an both fast and elegant way?

Two ways I have now, but both of them are inadequate: one is simply to add a new row called "asset type" in the operations table making the search pretty straightforward. The problem is that this is far from elegant since there is no direct connection between operations and asset types. Another solution would be to first call for a list of assets of some type and then do the look in "operations" table only for "assets included on this list". But this would be a processing monster since there could be dozens to hundreds of assets per type.

Is there any other way I couldn't figure or find out?

Comment: This is called a *join*, and it's more or less the reason RDBMSes like SQLite were invented.

Comment: Please check out info on joining and updating.  Give it a shot.  If it doesn't work, then post what you tried and we will help!

Comment: @EoinS thanks and j_random too. I had a look at *join*, but either the examples weren't clear enough, or it doesn't do exactly what I need. More specifically, I don't want to "join" tables in a query, I want to select the data of only one table but using a more advanced clause with information of another table.

Comment: What you're describing (both in your original question and in your comment) sounds to me exactly like what a join accomplishes (though, perhaps, indirectly).  It's not necessary to actually *output* all columns from all the tables -- maybe that's where you're going wrong?  FWIW, most databases (possibly SQLite too, though I don't know) also have a feature called *subqueries* which might allow you to express what you want in a more intuitive way -- though I have to remark that, internally, this is converted to (and equivalent to) a join.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it in the obvious way:

```
SELECT *
FROM Operations
WHERE AssetID IN (SELECT AssetID
                  FROM Assets
                  WHERE AssetType = ?);
```

The same could be done with a join

```
SELECT Operations.*
FROM Operations
JOIN Assets USING (AssetID)
WHERE AssetType = ?;
```